# How to pause track at certain duration using react-native-track-player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-track-player

File : **DataList.json**

```
[
  {
    "id": "abcd-001",
    "title": "Push Ups",
    "image": "imageOne",
    "description": "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. ",
    "duration": 10,
    "sets": "",
    "url" : "../assets/track1.mp3"
    "break": 40
  },
  {
    "id": "abcd-002",
    "title": "Pull Ups",
    "image": "imageTwo",
    "description": "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. ",
    "duration": 30,
    "sets": "",
    "url" : "../assets/track2.mp3"
    "break": 40
  },
]
```

**Component**: **Track.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      stopWithApp: true,
      capabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_STOP,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_NEXT,
      ],
      compactCapabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
      ],
    });
  }, []);

  const togglePlayBack = async () => {
    await TrackPlayer.add({
      title: title,
      id: id,
      url: require('../assets/audio/track1.mp3'),
      artist: 'Imran Sayed',
      duration: duration,
    });
  };

     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.main}>
        <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
          <Image source={Images[`${image}`]} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.info}>
          <Text style={styles.text}> {title} </Text>
          <Text style={styles.description}> {description} </Text>
          <Text style={styles.duration}> Duration - {duration} </Text>
          <Button
            color="darkslateblue"
            title="Start"
            onPress={togglePlayBack}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

I can't find any way to pause the music when the music duration is equal to the track's duration of DataList.json.

The music should be paused and should be resumed after the specified duration. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```js
const progress = TrackPlayer.useTrackPlayerProgress();

const getSectionDone = () => {
  if (progress.position > 5) {
    // to ensure that music is playing
    if (progress.position === progress.duration) {
      // finished
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Why make this a const arrow function? There is no `this` preservation, just make it a normal function with a `progress` argument, so you can call it for any `progress` object someone might want?

Comment: Also note I had to correct your code because you said `if (progress.position = progress.duration)` which is an assignment and is _very_ wrong.

Comment: oh really I wrote single  (=) for my condition? I'm so sorry buddy. at midnight my mind was laggy

Comment: It sounds cool but the issue is I can't any way to 'import useTrackPlayerProgress()'. The Hooks is not supported anymore I guess? Is there any way to use this .? :(

Comment: you don't `import useTrackPlayerProgress()`, that is not valid JS in any way: you import thins from files, e.g. `import { Tracker } from "tracker"` - what you're showing tries to import something from nowhere, _and_ you calling it as a function during the import so none of that makes sense, and is not what this answer tells you to do.

Comment: you just need import TrackPlayer from "react-native-track-player"                                     and use from TrackPlayer like this                                                                                 const progress = TrackPlayer.useTrackPlayerProgress();

Comment: ```await TrackPlayer.add({
      url: require('../assets/audio/track1.mp3'),
      duration: 10,
    });
    await TrackPlayer.play();
    if (Math.ceil(progress.position) > 3)
      if (Math.ceil(progress.position) == progress.duration) {
        await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
        await TrackPlayer.pause();
      } ``` . This function is called on Click .It successfully tracks the position and the total duration of the track. But the track doesn't stop when the position is equal to it's duration. Also tried using "===" operator but doesn't work ? :(  @mortezamoradi @Mike

Comment: you can subscribe position and duration with console.log you  cant do this in onclick function bro it just works in lifecycles like didUpdate and useEffect

Comment: Can you please give me any idea how do I implement the logic to stop the track inside useEffect hook when it meets the duration?  @mortezamoradi. Because the useEffect hook will be called initally when the app renders. Then how come it will stop the track which is playing after app rendering ?